# Why does storyboard load localized images randomly?

Tags: uistoryboard, autolayout

I have 2 small problems related, and I think the second is because of the first one.

The first one is that I have several UIButtons in my app, but no text, just background images.
These images are localized in 6 languages.
The problem is that when editing the views in the storyboard, I see that every button loads an image randomly (sometimes in English, others in Spanish, others in Russian…). It should be all in English, as I have the key :
CFBundleDevelopmentRegion
en

See the picture.
I guess everything is configured properly. Do you see anything strange?
Maybe this is an Xcode bug.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The second problem is that I'm using auto layouts. The reason is because the images in these buttons have different size depending on the language.
So, as the intrinsec content size changes, the button width changes (because there is no Width restriction).
The problem is, if I select a button an press the option "Size to Fit Content" in order to remove any width constraint, it seems it work perfectly  (when I launch the app the in different languages, the width is changed automatically depending on the language) but, when storyboard loads the image in a different language (the first problem), it seems the auto layout adds a width constraint automatically, and then when I launch the app again, the button's width are incorrect in most languages.
Do you have any idea what's going on?

A very dirty workaround perhaps is to create a UIButton descendant that removes any width restrictionon load. Don't know if that works.

I appreciate a lot your ideas regarding these problems.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a bug in Xcode, but it doesn't affect the final application.

I did the following.  Started a new Xcode project.  I used Storyboards with auto layout.  I did not use Base Internationalization.

I added 3 buttons to the main view.  I then created 3 images to use with the buttons and added them to a Resource group.  I saved the PNG files in the en.lproj folder with the storyboards.  I got the English version to work first.

I then went to the project and added French.  It brought up a dialog for all of the files it thought should be localized and it included the PNG files.  It copied all of them to the fr.lproj folder.  I then created the french versions of the PNG files and saved them with the original file names in the fr.lproj folder.

When viewing in Xcode, only one of the buttons was French.  The others were English.

When I ran the app in the simulator, the correct PNGs were used when the language was switched.

It is annoying, but does not appear to affect the app when it is running.

Exiting Xcode and re-launching it changes which ones are correct, but still does not work correctly.  You should probably submit a RADAR bug with Apple. http://bugreporter.apple.com/